# Using java classes in Grails

Tags: groovy, grails

I have a Java\Spring\Hibernate application - complete with domain classes which are basically Hibernate POJOs

There is a piece of functionality that I think can be written well in Grails.

I wish to reuse the domain classes that I have created in the main Java app

What is the best way to do so ?

Should I write new domain classes extending the Java classes ? this sounds tacky
Or Can I 'generate' controllers off the Java domain classes ?

What are the best practices around reusing Java domain objects in Grails\Groovy
I am sure there must be others writing some pieces in grails\groovy

If you know about a tutorial which talks about such an integration- that would be awesome !!!

PS: I am quite a newbie in grails-groovy so may be missing the obvious. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really want/need to use Grails rather than just Groovy?

Grails really isn't something you can use to add a part to an existing web app. The whole "convention over configuration" approach means that you pretty much have to play by Grails' rules, otherwise there is no point in using it. And one of those rules is that domain objects are Groovy classes that are heavily "enhanced" by the Grails runtime.

It might be possible to have them extend existing Java classes, but I wouldn't bet on it - and all the Spring and Hibernate parts of your existing app would have to be discarded, or at least you'd have to spend a lot of effort to make them work in Grails. You'll be fighting the framework rather than profiting from it.

IMO you have two options:

- Rewrite your app from scratch in Grails while reusing as much of the existing code as possible.
- Keep your app as it is and add new stuff in Groovy, without using Grails.

The latter is probably better in your situation. Grails is meant to create new web apps very quickly, that's where it shines. Adding stuff to an existing app just isn't what it was made for.

**EDIT:**
Concerning the clarification in the comments: if you're planning to write basically a data entry/maintenance frontend for data used by another app and have the DB as the only communication channel between them, that might actually work quite well with Grails; it can certainly be configured to use an existing DB schema rather than creating its own from the domain classes (though the latter is less work).

Comment: Thanks - what you said makes sense

A clarification to my Q...
The add-on I am talking about will exist as a separate app by itself. It will basically do 'CRUD' for objects that are 'processed' by the main app.

At the bare minimum- they will share just the Data model and if I get lucky the Java domain objects as well. 
I have no intention or need to reuse further.

Comment: Do you have a lot of experience with Grails?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: I wouldn't say "a lot" - basically one project's worth of.

Comment: Please, don't answer questions, where you have no real experience or just half-baked knowledge... Grails is a great framework, where you can integrate already written java/hibernate/spring code with almost no effort.

Answer (score 19):

Knowing just how well Groovy and Grails excel at integrating with existing Java code, I think I might be a bit more optimistic than Michael about your options.

First thing is that you're already using Spring and Hibernate, and since your domain classes are already POJOs they should be easy to integrate with. Any Spring beans you might have can be specified in an XML file as usual (in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml`) or much more simply using the [Spring bean builder](http://www.grails.org/Spring+Bean+Builder) feature of Grails. They can then be accessed by name in any controller, view, service, etc. and worked with as usual.

Here are the options, as I see them, for integrating your domain classes and database schema:

- Bypass GORM and load/save your domain objects exactly as you're already doing.

  Grails doesn't force you to use GORM, so this should be quite straightforward: create a `.jar` of your Java code (if you haven't already) and drop it into the Grails app's `lib` directory. If your Java project is Mavenized, it's even easier: Grails 1.1 works with Maven, so you can create a `pom.xml` for your Grails app and add your Java project as a dependency as you would in any other (Java) project.

  Either way you'll be able to `import` your classes (and any supporting classes) and proceed as usual. Because of Groovy's tight integration with Java, you'll be able to create objects, load them from the database, modify them, save them, validate them etc. exactly as you would in your Java project. You won't get all the conveniences of GORM this way, but you would have the advantage of working with your objects in a way that already makes sense to you (except maybe with a bit less code thanks to Groovy). You could always try this option first to get something working, then consider one of the other options later if it seems to make sense at that time.

  One tip if you do try this option: abstract the actual persistence code into a Grails service (`StorageService` perhaps) and have your controllers call methods on it rather than handling persistence directly. This way you could replace that service with something else down the road if needed, and as long as you maintain the same interface your controllers won't be affected.
- Create new Grails domain classes as subclasses of your existing Java classes.

  This could be pretty straightforward if your classes are already written as proper beans, i.e. with getter/setter methods for all their properties. Grails will see these inherited properties as it would if they were written in the simpler Groovy style. You'll be able to specify how to validate each property, using either simple validation checks (not null, not blank, etc.) or with closures that do more complicated things, perhaps calling existing methods in their POJO superclasses.

  You'll almost certainly need to tweak the mappings via the [GORM mapping DSL](http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Mapping+DSL) to fit the realities of your existing database schema. Relationships would be where it might get tricky. For example, you might have some other solution where GORM expects a join table, though there may even be a way to work around differences such as these. I'd suggest learning as much as you can about GORM and its mapping DSL and then experiment with a few of your classes to see if this is a viable option.
- Have Grails use your existing POJOs and Hibernate mappings directly.

  I haven't tried this myself, but according to Grails's [Hibernate Integration page](http://www.grails.org/Hibernate+Integration) this is supposed to be possible: "Grails also allows you to write your domain model in Java or re-use an existing domain model that has been mapped using Hibernate. All you have to do is place the necessary 'hibernate.cfg.xml' file and corresponding mappings files in the '%PROJECT_HOME%/grails-app/conf/hibernate' directory. You will still be able to call all of the dynamic persistent and query methods allowed in GORM!"

  Googling "gorm legacy" turns up a number of helpful discussions and examples, for example [this blog post](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2008/11/07/san-gria-update--mapping-the-legacy-db-from-hell.html) by Glen Smith (co-author of the soon-to-be-released *Grails in Action*) where he shows a Hibernate mapping file used to integrate with "the legacy DB from Hell". *Grails in Action* has a chapter titled "Advanced GORM Kungfu" which promises a detailed discussion of this topic. I have a pre-release PDF of the book, and while I haven't gotten to that chapter yet, what I've read so far is very good, and the book covers many topics that aren't adequately discussed in other Grails books.

Sorry I can't offer any personal experience on this last option, but it does sound doable (and quite promising). Whichever option you choose, let us know how it turns out!

Answer (score 3):

This post provides some suggestions for using grails for [wrapping existing Java classes in a web framework](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=333).